# bootstrap,no work grid (div class)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

this is link ex:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_stacked_to_hor&stacked=h

```html
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do want to do ?

Comment: I want to layout the page by div

Answer (score 2):

you have to call

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

then your code will work

Comment: I want to layout the page by div